# Django Template Value Passed to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I am working on a turn-based game where players can, but don't have to, gain ownership of certain spaces on the game board.  My detail view in shows the spaces owned by each player, and I use a loop to display all owned spaces:

```
<small class="text-muted">Spaces Owned</small>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% for space in player.space_set.all %}
      <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#spaceModal" id="modalButton">
       {{ space.name }}
      </a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

I want to be able to populate a modal with all detailed information about whichever space is clicked on (hence why I'm using the anchor tag instead of a div, though I guess it might not matter as much).  The modal would look something like this, though the goal is to populate it using appropriate IDs, etc using the response from the AJAX call instead of the template variables currently used as placeholders:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="spaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
            <h2>{{ space.name }}</h2>
            <div class="float-left">{{ space.location }}</div>
            <div class="float-right">{{ space.defense_points }}</div>
            <br />
            <div class="float-right">{{ space.attack_points }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is use an AJAX call to populate the modal for each space as it is clicked.  I have the server-side function set up okay and it is correctly returning the JSON needed when I process a simple get request (I'm using the following url pattern):

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:game>/space_data/<int:space>', get_space_data, name = 'get_space_data'),
]
```

with my views.py defined as:

```
def get_space_data(request,game,space):
    game = Game.objects.get(pk=game)
    space = game.space_set.get(location=space)
    data = {
        'name': space.name,
        'location': space.location,
        'defense_points': space.defense,
        'attack_points': space.attack,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Right now the JS that I'm using to test usage is the following:

```
<script>
  $("#modalButton").click(function(){
    var space = "{{ space }}"
    console.log(space)
    alert('Modal Button Clicked')
  })
</script>
```

**Summary**

Essentially all I want to be able to do, which I can't figure out how to do, is pass the space variable to the JS code so that I can build the appropriate AJAX call within the last script code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You're not making an AJAX call at the moment. When you do, it will be able to access the response from the Django view as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To touch on what Daniel wrote, what I was asking was simply how to pass Django template data to a JQuery script, which I would then use in an AJAX call.  I figured it out, though, and will post my answer here instead of just deleting the question.

The modal pop-up anchor tag should look like this:

```
<small class="text-muted">Spaces Owned</small>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% for space in player.space_set.all %}
      <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#spaceModal" id="modalButton" data-location="{{ space.location }}">
       {{ space.name }}
      </a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

and the resulting JQuery code is as follows:

```
<script>
  $("#modalButton").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('location'))
    alert('Modal Button Clicked')
  })
</script>
```

From this I will be able to add an actual AJAX call to the script and pull the data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

in this way you send the variables to the js to use them in the ajax

```
{% block scripts %}
    <script>
     var name  = {{space.name}}
     var location = {{space.location}}
    </script>
   <!-- JS Template -->
   <script src="{% static 'folder/name.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock scripts %}
```

and your js

```
$.ajax({

       url: url,
       method: "",
       data: {

         "name" : name,
         "location":location

       },
       success: function (_response) {


       },
)
```